# Question about Fubini's Theorem for Riemann Integral functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f: [0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be given such that

$$ f(x,y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & : x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
       2y & : x \notin \mathbb{Q}
     \end{array}
   \right. $$

I have found that

$$ \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 f(x,y) dy dx = 1 $$

But, I am having difficulties trying to find

$$ \int\limits_0^1 \overline{ \int\limits_0^1} f(x,y) dxdy$$

The reason I am trying to find this is to show that

$$\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 f(x,y) dy dx \neq \int\limits_0^1 \overline{ \int\limits_0^1} f(x,y) dxdy $$

So that by Fubini's theorem, $f$ cannot be integrable on $[0,1] \times [0,1] $.

Any suggestions would be greatly welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

procede carefully! I would suggest you to write $f$ as a linear combination of indicator functions.

Let's rewrite f:
$f(x,y)=\mathbb{1}_{x\in \mathbb{Q}}+\mathbb{1}_{x\notin\mathbb{Q}}.2y$

Then the integrals becomes

$\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^1\int_0^1\mathbb{1}_{x\in \mathbb{Q}}+\mathbb{1}_{x\notin\mathbb{Q}}.2ydxdy=
\int_0^1\int_0^1\mathbb{1}_{x\in \mathbb{Q}}dx+\int_0^1\mathbb{1}_{x\notin\mathbb{Q}}.2ydxdy=\int_0^1 2y\int_0^11-\mathbb{1}_{x\in \mathbb{Q}}dxdy=\int_0^1 2y(1-0)dy=\int_0^1 2ydy=1$

In the opposite direction:

$\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)dydx=\int_0^1\int_0^1\mathbb{1}_{x\in \mathbb{Q}}+\mathbb{1}_{x\notin\mathbb{Q}}.2ydydx=\int_0^1\mathbb{1}_{x\in\mathbb{Q}}+\mathbb{1}_{x\notin\mathbb{Q}}dx=\int_0^11dx=1$

check please my computation to make sure there is no mistakes. But it seems to be Lebesgue integrable

Comment: but $f$ is not riemann integrable ?

Comment: if you take $y\neq 1/2$ (y not constant 1/2) it is countably discontinuous hence not riemann Itegrable

Comment: uhmmm, I cannot see why it is discontinuous. If you want $50$ points, you can answer this question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757017/question-concerning-the-integrability-of-a-function

Comment: Your function f is a clearly discontinuous function.. I don't get what you mean with your last comment. Anyway as an advice: Fubini's THM requires that your function is in $L^1([0,1]\times [0,1])$ in your case. To prove this one may often use Tonelli's THM. It can happen that both integrations above are equal but the function not integrable. In your case your function is in $L^1$ so it is correct that the integrations are equal

Comment: I still cannot see why $f$ is discontinuous everywhere except at $y   = \frac{1}{2} $. I mean, It makes sense intuitively, but I cannot prove this result rigoriously. Can you help me? thanks

Comment: Assume f is continuous in $v=(x_0,0)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$, then by def. $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0 s.t. |f(x_0,0)-f(x,y)|<\epsilon$ for $(x,y)=w\in B_\delta (v)$. Now you know that you can surly find an irrational number x in this open ball of v and so $|f(x_0,y_0)-f(x,0)|=|1-f(x,0)|=1>\epsilon$ and you get your contradiction